# Solve the integral: $\int \frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{\sin x+\sin^3 x}dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Here's what I tried:

$$ \int \frac{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}{\sin x(1+\sin^2 x)}dx = \int \frac{\cos^2x}{\sin x (1+\sin^2x)}dx - \int \frac{\sin^2x}{\sin x (1+\sin^2x)}dx  $$
I tried then to divide with $ \sin x $ and $ \cos x $. Tried to use some trigonometric identities, but it didn't work, I just complicated it more.

And I can't see something that I can substitute.

Comment: Did you consider that you can cancel one "sin(x)" in the second integral ?

Comment: The substitution $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$ will work, but the resulting rational function could be difficult to integrate.

Comment: Yes, I tried to cancel one $\sin x$.

Comment: An usual idea, but have you tried $t=\sin^2(x)$ ?

Comment: This expression could be integrated very easily! But only without $\sin$ and $\cos$ , of course.

Comment: Result: $\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}^3}\ln\frac{\sqrt{2}+\cos x }{\sqrt{2}-\cos x }+\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1-\cos x }{1+\cos x } +C$ . If you have problems then derivate this to get an idea how to integrate. It's senseful to transform your term to a term of $\cos$ and substitute $t:=\cos(x)$.

Comment: Thanks @Peter and user90369 for your comments, I solved it using Olvieria Oloa's hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write, with the change of variable $u=\cos x$,
$$
\int \frac{\cos^2x}{\sin x (1+\sin^2x)}dx=\int \frac{\cos^2x\:\sin x}{\sin^2 x (1+\sin^2x)}dx=-\int \frac{u^2}{(1-u^2) (2-u^2)}du
$$ and
$$
\int \frac{\sin^2x}{\sin x (1+\sin^2x)}dx=\int \frac{\sin x}{ 1+\sin^2x}dx=-\int \frac{du}{2-u^2}
$$ then the new integrals are easier to evaluate.